# Payment device compliance of PCI v2 AND PCIv3

Tags: pci-dss

Is there any known case of a pin pad device being compliant PCI v2 but by changing just a software component it becomes PCI v3 compliant?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that when you say PCI v2 and PCI v3 you mean the PCI PTS POI standard - ie the one for physical devices that include pin entry or are secure card readers. I’d personally be very surprised if a software upgrade changed the appropriate version number, because the hardware security profile changed between v2 and v3. The easiest way to check is on the PCI SSC website. All PTS devices are listed here:
https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/assessors_and_solutions/pin_transaction_devices

Comment: It looks like Prism Payment Technologies' TSM500i is the only thing on both the 2.x and 3.x lists. I have no idea how that works.

Comment: That's because it is a hardware security module (HSM), not a payment terminal. Confusingly they are listed in the same section of the SSC website but are tested to PTS HSM not PTS POI. The firmware is a different version between the v3 and v2 approvals.